# Download of files takes to much time

Tags: java, android

```
 URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("1", "The response is: " + response);


            in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

            out = new FileOutputStream(file);

            int bufferLength = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            while ((bufferLength = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
```

I am download small xml file, and then parsing it and creating objects from this file.

File size 3,8 kB. But it's take several second to show me some data after download start.
When I parse already downloaded file without internet connection it takes less then one second to show me data.
From that I concluded that problem is in this method.
PS I forgot to say, that it's downloading some small thumbnail pictures after that.

I've measured time

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<?> parseData(File dataFile) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();




    ArrayList<Training> list = new ArrayList<Training>();
    MyParser parser = new MyParser();
    MyFileDownloader downloader = new MyFileDownloader();
    try {
        list = parser.parseTrainings(dataFile);
        boolean networkAvaible = fragment.isNetworkAvailable();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (networkAvaible)
                downloader.downloadFile(list.get(i).getImageURL(), new File(fragment.getDataFolder(), "image"+i));
            String path = fragment.getDataFolder().getPath() + "/image"+i;
            Drawable im = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
            list.get(i).setImage(im);
        }

    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    Log.d("******TIME PASSED******", String.valueOf(elapsedTime));
    return list;
```

When there is internet connection and I need to download files it taking about 9-11 sec.
And when there is no need to download them it's taking about 0.5 sec. How can I decrease time of downloading this files?
The sum of file sizes is 5236 Mbits. It should be downloaded for less then 1 sec with my 20Mbps wi-fi. One or two seconds would be fine. But 9 or even 16 seconds? That's bad user experience.

Comment: Remove (in = new BufferedInputStream) use InputStream. Your code looks ok. May be there is some problem with your Network Speed.

Comment: No, it's about 20 Mbps on wi-fi.
And why not use Buffered Input? Shouldn't it be faster that way not slower?

Comment: I've considered using another AsyncTask to download needed files in getView() method of ListAdapter (I'm using custom ListFragment to represent the data to user). But I don't want that solution, because  the list is really small (5-10 elements).

Comment: BufferedInputStream may cause some problem while using with network file reading. I'm not sure this may be the cause for the present problem. But better to avoid it. When you use Async Task it appears slower because of progress bar initialization processing and sending message to close progress bar, will take time. With out Async task we can't use network on main thread, that is also there

Comment: It's not AsyncTask that makes it slow. It's downloading files parseData method. See the code above. I've measured size of files and time of download and edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use asynctask for downloading files.here is a good example, refer this.

> http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Comment: I'm already using it. This method invoked inside AsyncTask. The question question is why it takes so much time to download files? Can I make this quicker? Can it be that it just slow server.Right now files are on dropbox. I can probably measure time of download by getting system time... Maybe that would give some useful information, how do you think?